# The entity type is not part of the model for the current context - on NopCommerce

Tags: entity-framework, ef-code-first, nopcommerce

I am extending NopCommerce's entities. I've added a new table. Then
i define all properties, mappings all steps same as category, product or other new entites.

But when I rebuild Nop.Data project and debug project again, this error doesn't shown and it works fine, after some minutes or debug without rebuild Nop.Data, it appears again.

> #### Server Error in '/' Application
>
> ***The entity type ProductPlan is not part of the model for the current context.***
>
> ***Description:*** An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of
> the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more
> information about the error and where it originated in the code.
>
> ***Exception Details:*** System.invalidOperationException: The entity type
> ProductPlan is not part of the model for the current context.

[image: look like]

These classes are in Nop.Data project, not in any plugin..

```
public partial class ProductPlan : BaseEntity
{
    public virtual int ProductId { get; set; }
    public virtual int StoreId { get; set; }
    public virtual int CategoryId { get; set; }
    public virtual DateTime StartDate { get; set; }
    public virtual DateTime EndDate { get; set; }
    public virtual int DisplayOrder { get; set; }
    public virtual bool IsSlider { get; set; }
    public virtual bool Deleted { get; set; }

    
    public virtual Product Product { get; set; }
    public virtual Category Category { get; set; }
}

public partial class ProductPlanMap : NopEntityTypeConfiguration<ProductPlan>
{
    public ProductPlanMap()
    {
        this.ToTable("ProductPlan");
        this.Property(p => p.ProductId).IsRequired();
        this.Property(p => p.StoreId).IsRequired();
        this.Property(p => p.CategoryId).IsRequired();
        this.Property(p => p.DisplayOrder).IsRequired();
        this.Property(p => p.StartDate).IsRequired();
        this.Property(p => p.EndDate).IsRequired();
        this.Property(p => p.IsSlider).IsRequired();
        this.Property(p => p.Deleted).IsRequired();
    }
}
```

Is there any suggestion or solution ?

Comment: Its strange issue. did you try re-build after a clean? If that dint help, go to every bin folder and delete all the dlls and try.

Comment: @Eray did you got any solution ? i am also stuck in that part. Please help me

Comment: @Umar i solved it to bring them into new project and leave unnecessary plugins.